# Javascript/jQuery positioning issue

Tags: jquery

Here is the problematic part of my code:

```
$('#chat-bar').prepend('<li id="chat-button-with-'+userid+'"><a href="#">'+username+'</a></li>');

$('#chat').prepend('<div class="chat-box" id="chat-box-with-'+userid+'"></div>');

parentright = $('body').width() - $('#chat-button-with-'+userid).offset().left;

$('#chat-box-with-'+userid).css({right:parentright, bottom:'24px'});
```

What I'm trying to do is line #chat-box-with-n up with its respective button, #chat-button-with-n

userid and username and so on are all set before this, so this is not the issue. In fact, after the page loads, if I set userid to 3 in the console and then do:

```
parentright = $('body').width() - $('#chat-button-with-'+userid).offset().left;
```

I'll get the proper result. Yet it doesn't seem to be able to get this result after just appending it. What am I doing wrong?

If I put `alert(parentright)` just after the line, I'll just get the body width. So $('#chat-button-with-'+userid).offset().left seems to be 0 at that point. Do I need to do this some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the only issue, but you didn't set the value type (px, em, etc.) to the css function:

```
$('#chat-box-with-'+userid).css({right:parentright, bottom:'24px'});
```

should be

```
$('#chat-box-with-'+userid).css({right:parentright+"px", bottom:'24px'});
```

**UPDATE:**

I was unable to reproduce the issue, please see if this example does what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/xTrQ9/2/

Instead of setting the `right` property and introducing unnecessary math, I am using the `left` property instead. Note that changing the position of the `#chat-bar` also changes the position of the box, or in other words, the two are vertically aligned.

Comment: Oops, nice catch. It's not the issue though.

Comment: I did some testing and can't reproduce the issue. The left offset of the prepended element of course depends on the offset of the `#chat-bar` at the time of creation. Are you sure `#chat-bar's` offset is correct? Can you edit this jsfiddle to reproduce the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/xTrQ9/

Comment: To further clarify what I mean, it could be that `#chat-bar's` offset changes after prepending takes place, so `#chat-button-with-n's` offset would have whatever value `#chat-bar` had before moving. As I was unable to reproduce the problem with the provided code, without having some more js/html code it would be difficult to guess what the issue is.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I think I've solved the issue, and it's a very silly one. A div that contained all of this content was set to display:none; until the javascript enabled it. I guess this meant there was no offset since it wasn't visible.